# How can I edit the xticks on a python twinx?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got two pandas series I would like to plot on the same axis, using a twinx.  Here is a picture of what it looks like:

```
fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5) = plt.subplots(nrows = 5,ncols = 1, figsize = (8,13))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5)


ax1_1 = ax1.twinx()

df[["Var"]].plot(ax = ax1, label = 'Variance')
df[['w2']].plot(ax = ax1_1, color = 'g', label = '$w$')


ax1.locator_params('y',nbins = 5)
ax1_1.locator_params('y', nbins = 5)

ax1.set_ylabel('AC', labelpad = 10)
ax1_1.set_ylabel('w',  labelpad = 10)
ax1.legend(loc = 'upper left')
ax1_1.legend()
```

[image]

I'd like to edit the x axis ticks, but using `ax1.set_xticks()` and `ax1.set_xticklabels()` doesn't seem to work.  Furthermore, why are there are no x ticks after I execute the code found above?  Shouldn't the ticks be the index of the Series?